# My water lines are mixing but i'm not sure how or where

Tags: plumbing, water

UPDATE: here's a video of the situation: https://youtu.be/NoTIYk_x8EU
In this video the hot water heater valves are closed. There is no recirculation. All sinks and toilets are closed at the valves. All the shower cartridges are removed like the ones shown.

If I disconnect the water heater and turn on the main, cold water flows through BOTH pipes that go to the water heater. The cold line (correctly) and the hot line (this is backwards).

I have turned off the value on both lines, turned off all the valves on all the sinks and appliances. The only thing left is the shower valves. I thought it might be a valve, so i removed the cartridges from all of them exposing hot and cold holes in the valves.

I turned on the cold water (the water heater is completely shut off with valves on both pipes) and of the 3 showers, only the shower on the bottom floor had water come directly out of the valve. If i put my finger in to plug the cold water hole, cold water also comes out of the other. If i remove my finger, the hole that's supposed to be hot loses pressure but still flows quite a bit.

The lines are definitely crossed but i can't see where. The house is made of concrete and cinder block (this is typical in this area of mexico) so it's not easy to break open the walls. Is there any way I can detect where this crossover is? Is there anything else it can be?

Comment: I just bought this house so I have no idea if this is a new or old issue.

Comment: Not familiar with Mexican construction. How is the plumbing built into the concrete?  In some countries, new concrete houses have conduits built in to the walls and plastic pipes (Pex) run through the conduits, with all fittings exposed.  I don't imagine you're so lucky or you would have said.  What do you have?

Comment: You have a main cold water valve this is normal if the main is not fully closing there will still be water why do you think they are backwards? Water back flowing through a valve or recirculating system is also not unusual. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's pretty much all PVC pipes running through cinder blocks, so there isn't really any way to pull the pipes out without knocking some pretty big holes in the wall. Wherever the walls are opened to work on things, they are resealed by just filling it in with a soft type of concrete.

Comment: @EdBeal When the hot water line is completely shut off at the heater, there is pressurized cold water coming out of all of the hot water connections. There is no recirculation. When the water heater valve is off, the hot water pipes should be bone dry. They have pressurized water.

Comment: .... This prevents the hot water from getting to any of the faucets when the water heater is connected properly.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the lower floor shower valve. My guess is that valve is allowing the cold to flow through it to the hot side. By chance is there another valve in that shower to control the flow to the shower head.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose i'll ppost a video in a minute, but i removed the cartridge from the lower shower, and the water comes out of both inlets. so it's not crossing here. there is no other valve for switching to a tub or anything, there is just a regular, single shower head

Comment: @PlatinumGoose here's a video : https://youtu.be/NoTIYk_x8EU

Comment: I also noticed that if i plug the cold water with my finger, the hot water increases it's pressure. it's not immediate, but it is pretty quick, so it seems like the cross might be a couple feet away from here. this shower also happens to be on the opposite side of the wall with the water heater.

Comment: Based on your last comment about the quick response to opening/plugging the cold side of the shower valve and that it is sharing a wall with the heater, it would be reasonable to 1) confirm your "timing" experiment by repeating it at another fixture that is further away.  See if that takes longer to respond. 2) If it does take longer to respond, the cross is probably in that wall.   I think you've made it clear though, you either need to live with this or start breaking walls.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem. It involved opening a few walls and experimenting with cutting some pipes. Unfortunately listening devices were of no use. I was able to track down some people who worked on this house and others nearby that had the same problem, although the location of the problem was a little different.

In both the downstairs and upstairs bathrooms, the shower spout and knobs are on the west side of the shower. They were originally designed to be on the east side. They had already put pipes going to the east side of the shower and instead of capping those off, they decided to connect them together. Why? I have no idea. Maybe they didn't have caps, thought that nobody would know, or forgot to fix it later. In any event, the solution was to cut these connections and cap them off.

The first was slightly easier to find. The pipes for the second floor can be seen in the ceiling through the holes for the lights. There were hot/cold pipes going to the wrong side of the shower. We figured that was the issue, opened the ceiling and cut it. For the first floor, the pipes ran under the shower, maybe in the foundation, so we weren't sure how to open it. But one of the guys had the idea to open the wall on the outside. With some measurements about where the shower would be, they were able to cut a single hole about 3 inches wide right where the pipe was. Cut it and capped it and we're all good.

Thanks for all the suggestions and comments!

Comment: Thanks for coming back to let us know what you did!

Comment: Yes, thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 1):

Your cross connect could be in any mixing valve, inside or outside.

Sometimes an outside shower or hot supply can have a deliberate cross valve near its shutoff to allow blowing for winterization.

Another purpose of the cross valve is to allow a pressure balanced outside shower to work even if its hot supply is shut off. (A pressure balanced valve will block flow if either cold or hot has no pressure, e.g. when either one is shut off)

Also, if you know the diameter of the tubing/piping, you can estimate the location of the cross flow by measuring the time to build pressure, as you have observed, on the hot side.

You need the flow rate with the main valve squeezed as you have in the video, and the diameter of the pipes. If you need help with the math, let us know.

If the diameter varies and you don't know where, then regrettably this won't work directly, but you could place bounds on the distance: calculate the distance once based on assuming one diameter, and then again based on another possible diameter. Perhaps these bounds are close enough to be useful in narrowing the search.

For the math: determine the flow by measuring the time it takes to fill a container of known volume, e.g. 1Ga milk jug. Now you have the flow rate .

If it takes for instance 80s to fill a 1Ga jug, your 8s timing at the shower means 0.1Ga in the pipes. The fill time of course depends on the setting of your main shut off.

Type your numbers in the calculate at https://www.omnicalculator.com/construction/pipe-volume

Using the 80s example with 0.5 in pipes, that comes to almost 10ft distance.

The accuracy also depends on the residual fill of the pipes. So for a reliable measurement it would be good if you could blow the pipes (I realize this is not easy). That could explain the comparatively short time to get flow at the kitchen.

[image]

Comment: The sizes seem to be consistent throughout the house with the cold water about 1" and the hot water about 1/2". I tried opening up the shower again. There was already a slow trickle from the hot without touching the cold. When i blocked cold with my finger it took about 5 seconds to get some bubbles from the hot then 3 more seconds until it was at it's peak. Meanwhile with the kitchen sink open, there was no water on either side. If i plugged both sides of teh shower it took only 4 seconds until there was water to either the hot or cold. Kitchen is approx 25 to 30ft away from the shower.

Comment: i tried shutting the shower completely to see if the kitchen would do the same thing but since it's a single mixer it seemed to have constantly the same pressure in both hot and cold

Comment: @DAB  I edited my answer to include the calculations. Looks like the cross is not far. I hope this helps. Are you saying it took 4s for flow to start in the kitchen? That could be because of residual water in the pipes.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking, probably all the pipes below the night of the shower valve were full? Because the water would be level across all pipes.

Comment: I think at least gives me confidence in opening the wall behind the shower. Fingers crossed!

Comment: It's still very unlikely it would be the pipes: it would take two cracked pipes for cross flow to happen inside the cemented walls. What is there in the 10ft-ish radius? Is there a separate instant hot water somewhere? Did you open & remove or shutoff all your mixing valves & faucets? Is there a washing machine connected to both?

Comment: i tried shutting off everything. within 10 feet there is only the washer, and the sink and toilet in the same bathroom. they are all off at the valves. i dont think it's a cracked pipe that's feeding into the next, i think when they built this place they just screwed up and connected the pipes. i'm told sometimes they do that to make it easier to check the pressure. maybe they forgot to undo that.

Comment: @DAB ... "maybe they forgot to undo that" pfff, ok you have a good reason to open the wall. Best of luck. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: it's a nightmare. we opened the wall by the water heater. the hot water was broken into 2 sections. one that goes up, one that goes down. so we figured we would pull out the T and see if the extra water came from up or down. my guess was down based on other tests. sure enough it came from the bottom. then i plugged it with my finger and it also came from the top. we dug deeper and found another T. did the same. it's definitely not coming from the lower shower. im trying to track down the builder and schematics before we open more.

Comment: So you are getting a cross feed through the cement? Wow. If you have  pic, perhaps you can link to it here (and delete afterwards), I'm curious and can't quite visualize your piping but appreciate it's a nightmare. Thanks for the update!

Comment: I don't think it's through the cement. I got an electronic stethoscope and trying to figure out where the water goes. But I'm looking at how a recirculating valve works for a pump. I don't have a pump but I wonder if there could be a recirculating valve installed causing this?

Comment: A recirc circuit would involve the hot pipe to a far point in the house, or perhaps the kitchen, and then a third pipe/tube back to the water heater. The recirc return is simply connected to the hot at the far end. It would not involve the cold, unless someone connected it wrong, perhaps at the far end accidentally connecting cold to recirc instead of hot to recirc. Or swapping hot and cold at the heater or elsewhere before/at the faucet, before tying in the recirc.

Comment: i was thinking it was either installed wrong or maybe it broke because our water is really hard. sometimes we get sand sized grit in the pipes. but doing my research on that, these are usually installed under a sink or somewhere, not inside the walls. so i think im back to the drawing board.

Comment: You are right about the recirc staring under the sink. The tank would have a recirc intake. I think the old pics you had showed non. Now, to be clear: did you find broken pipe in the wall? Or did it break as you opened the wall? I'm not sure what you meant with your earlier comment If you link to a picture, we can look at it together.

Comment: The pipes did not break when we opened the wall. We cut them to see how it would affect the house. And put cameras in them to see where they go. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O58bYodcpvXPdew15keQ5SAVzokjwzW1/view?usp=drivesdk this is where the heater goes. 1 goes to the ceiling of the first floor which breaks to the points of the 2nd floor. Then it continues to the 3rd floor somewhere. We out a cam inside with the system empty, turned it on and saw water pouring into it from the ceiling of the first floor. No water above that.

Comment: We also had water coming up from #2 which is why we think there are two bridges / crosses whatever you call them. 3 we cut to check with the camera. It goes straight down into the ground then turns in the direction of the 1st floor bathroom. There is also water coming out of that. 4 is the back of the shower of the 1st floor bathroom. That has no water coming back from the hot so that one is ok.

Comment: I was finally able to solve this. I'll post it as a new answer.

Comment: @DAB wow what a headache! So did the East/West switch amount to about 10ft as calculated? Just curious to know if the time measurement trick was of any help.

Comment: I think, more or less. the width of the shower is about 6 feet, plus about 2 or 3 feet height on each side from where i was testing to the loop. but i guess that would double because both sides of the loop would count?